# MMAP sharing for multiple objects

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

I am creating a CMA (Contiguous Memory Allocator ) user side driver and I have mmaped some region of space.  If I create a second object, which wants to mmap the same memory region, is it possible to search that it has been mmaped already and pass back that address?  Currently, each object will make its own mmap, it works but is that a good idea in terms of performance?

The class is used to mmap different regions of memory, depending on what is passed in the constructor, so static will not work.

Comment: "is that a good idea in terms of performance?" Why not measure it?

Comment: measure against what?  I have no alternative methods yet :)

Comment: mmapping it twice vs mmapping it once and reusing that mmap.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve, but I'm guessing you want to optimise the allocation so that you get less overhead if the same region is used multiple times within the same application.

The kernel needs to track each reference to a page of physical memory, so if you "track allocations and return the same pointer" in your code, you will need to reference count the allocations yourself, and only do the allocation/free when it's needed.

I would perform that at the user-mode level, basically keeping a `std::map` (or similar) which is keyed on the underlying memory and size, and then reference counting that allocation, and only call `munmap` when reference count reaches zero (and of course only call `mmap` when the region can't be found). It gets more "fun" if you have multiple allocations of different sizes to the same region, but I don't think there is a way that works (well) that can be implemented for this - at least not if the second call requests a larger allocation.

The benefit of doing this in user-mode is clear: if you ever make a mistake in the accounting, the kernel will still release the memory if the application stops. And the allocation of memory for the `std::map` [or it's equivalent] in kernel mode will also be much harder to deal with.

Comment: This is kind of what I thought.  I will leave it up to the user of my driver to maintain the already mapped addresses and counts.